# JsonPath query?

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "myresource1": {
      "Properties": {
        "keyA": {
          "Ref": "resource2"
        },
        "keyB": "something",
        "keyC": {
          "another object": {
            "Ref": "resource3"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "resource2": {
      "Properties": {
        "keyA": 1,
        "keyB": 2
      }
    },
    "resource3": {}
  }
}
```

I'd like a `JSON Path` query that finds all `Resource`s that have `Properties` that have a `Ref` object in them.

So in the JSON above, `myresource1` has two properties that satisfy this condition and the `Ref`s are `resource2` and `resource3`.

Is this possible?

I found this query works:

```
$..Properties.*..Ref
```

It gives me a list of paths:

```
[
   "$['Resources']['myresource1']['Properties']['keyA']['Ref']",
   "$['Resources']['myresource1']['Properties']['keyC']['another object']['Ref']"
]
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: So are you trying to grab the whole of `myresource1` or a specific part?

Comment: @JackFleeting i need the Resource name and the value of the `Ref` attribute

Comment: Looks like you can get the one or the other, but not both. To get the value of the `Ref` attribute, you can use `$..Properties..[?(@.Ref)].Ref`, but to get both, you would need to be able to use nested filters or climb back up to the parent, which seems impossible with jsonpath (or even jsonpath+). See long discussion here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287. The only thing I can think of is convert the json to xml and then use xpath, which can easily get you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting!